# What is the Jhipster registry url after deploying it on tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to deploy jhipster registry war on tomcat, deployment is successful but I am unable to access the url. I tried `http://localhost:8080/jhipster-registry-2.5.8/` and `http://localhost:8761/#/` neither worked. I know that default port for registry is 8761, Does Tomcat overwrites it?

```
2017-02-23 10:19:05.782  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.ApplicationWebXml  : The following profiles are active: prod
2017-02-23 10:19:08.230  WARN 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider decl
2017-02-23 10:19:09.221 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.r.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Registering JVM gauges
2017-02-23 10:19:09.258 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.r.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-02-23 10:19:12.162  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application configuration, using profiles: [prod]
2017-02-23 10:19:12.176 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-02-23 10:19:12.188 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-02-23 10:19:12.190 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-02-23 10:19:12.198 DEBUG 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering Caching HTTP Headers Filter
2017-02-23 10:19:12.200  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application fully configured
2017-02-23 10:19:12.227  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistry   : Running with Spring profile(s) : [prod]
2017-02-23 10:19:15.853  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2017-02-23 10:19:15.883  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1487863155883 with initial instances count: 0
2017-02-23 10:19:16.072  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2017-02-23 10:19:16.075  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2017-02-23 10:19:16.313  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-02-23 10:19:16.321  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-02-23 10:19:16.321  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-02-23 10:19:16.322  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2017-02-23 10:19:16.802  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2017-02-23 10:19:16.836  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2017-02-23 10:19:16.838  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2017-02-23 10:19:21.092  WARN 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-02-23 10:19:21.097  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-02-23 10:19:21.116  WARN 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-02-23 10:19:21.117  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-02-23 10:19:23.779  INFO 89248 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2017-02-23 10:19:23.794  INFO 89248 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2017-02-23 10:19:23.801  INFO 89248 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2017-02-23 10:19:23.854  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.ApplicationWebXml  : Started ApplicationWebXml in 21.486 seconds (JVM running for 40.931)
2017-02-23 10:19:23.938  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2017-02-23 10:19:24.045  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-02-23 10:19:24.052  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-02-23 10:19:24.052  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-02-23 10:19:24.053  INFO 89248 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\jhipster-registry-2.5.war has finished in 36,797 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.060 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\docs
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.110 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\docs has finished in 50 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.111 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\examples
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.530 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\examples has finished in 419 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.530 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\host-manager
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.578 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\host-manager has finished in 48 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.580 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\manager
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.606 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\manager has finished in 27 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.607 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\ROOT
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.636 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\ROOT has finished in 28 ms
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.644 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.663 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
23-Feb-2017 10:19:25.666 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 41071 ms
2017-02-23 10:20:22.433 DEBUG 89248 --- [apr-8080-exec-9] i.g.j.r.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint  : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2017-02-23 10:20:23.804  INFO 89248 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2017-02-23 10:21:23.804  INFO 89248 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 1ms
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have updated my question with the tomcat log. It looks the same as when I run mvnw command but does not give the url at the end of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your setup and got same problems. 
Weird thing is that running

```
curl http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/jhipster-registry-2.5.8/
```

works fine: I get the home page contents.

So something does not work in the browser.

Using another port than 8761 and a context path different than `/` (in your case `/jhipster-registry-2.5.8/`) means that you must modify several application properties in registry's `application*.yml` and also the `bootstrap.yml` files from all your services and gateways registering with this registry.

To avoid this, I changed tomcat's port  to 8761 and renamed the registry war file to `ROOT.war` but it still does not work.

To make it work would require some significant effort in debugging. So, I highly recommend that you stick to the recommended usage: either using `java -jar jhipster-registry.war` or using docker.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it. I am auto deploying the registry war file to tomcat using bamboo into aws elastic beanstalk. Now then I have to find a way to use java - jar command there,Please let me know if you know the steps.. Thank you.

Comment: if you're deploying to a cloud, maybe you should consider using docker.Also I'm not sure what's the benefit of using bamboo unless you plan to modify registry's code. Also you could use our AWS sub generator for deploying to AWS https://jhipster.github.io/aws/

Comment: I am actually new to Bomboo so I was trying to deploy the registry first, even though I am able to deploy it I am unable to access the url on the browser. We are not using docker yet so I will have to research on how to run the one time command to run registry in elastic beanstalk.