# Deploying jhipster registry to external Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, jhipster

I have a locally working jhipster-registry which I want to deploy to a test server, I created the war and uploaded it, but can't access the registry through the test server, when I click on the registry link it redirects me to SERVERURL:8080/jhipster-registry and I get the message:
"Your request cannot be processed".

Meanwhile in the logs I get:

```
"2017-02-24 13:10:24.278 DEBUG 7424 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] i.g.j.r.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint  : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2017-02-24 13:10:58.452  INFO 7424 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

this is the tomcat log:

```
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 5 2016 20:18:12 UTC
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.9.0
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.828 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_112-b15
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.830 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.830 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.831 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\conf\logging.properties
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.835 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\temp
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.2.
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
24-Feb-2017 14:37:35.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
24-Feb-2017 14:37:36.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
24-Feb-2017 14:37:36.841 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8761"]
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.103 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.107 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.110 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.110 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1815 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
24-Feb-2017 14:37:37.187 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\jhipster-registry.war
24-Feb-2017 14:37:45.192 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.127 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\jhipster-registry.war has finished in 37,939 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.129 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\docs
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.157 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\docs has finished in 28 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\examples
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.553 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirctory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\examples has finished in 395 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.560 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\host-manager
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.606 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\host-manager has finished in 46 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.607 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\manager
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.673 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\manager has finished in 66 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.690 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\ROOT
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.715 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Eva\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\ROOT has finished in 25 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.720 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8761]
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.734 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
24-Feb-2017 14:38:15.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 38627 ms
```

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: in the console i get jhipster-registry/ 401 Unauthorized

Comment: This is the normal reply when you are not authenticated. Have you tried to pass the login/password in the URL? something like http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/jhipster-registry ?

Comment: I put the log in the answer

Comment: And yes i tried putting the user and password directly to the URL

Comment: Any reason why you want to deploy in Tomcat rather than running the executable war? I'm not sure someone has tried this with the registry since we enabled basic auth. It's gonna be harder for sure. Where did you configure spring active profile for the registry?

Comment: I want to deploy the registry on test server together with the micro-services so I can test them, I already tried with both dev and prod profile.

Comment: Deploying all microservices, gateways and registry into one tomcat server does not make sense in a microservice architecture. How do you expect to scale up?

Comment: It's just for testing purposes, but for my problem what do you suggest?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395478/what-is-the-jhipster-registry-url-after-deploying-it-on-tomcat please read my answer here.

Comment: You were right, it started working once I run the executable war, you can add that in the answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Comment: It's OK as it 's a duplicate, you can even delete your question if you want.